# Docusign send email after document completion only

Tags: docusignapi

We are attempting to use a listener to pick up on envelope events and to automate grabbing the completed docs from Docusign and putting them in our document management system. What we would like to do is to listen for all events, like document sent, document received, etc, but only notify the sender when the envelope was voided or declined, not when the receiver signs the documents and the envelope is complete. Is such a thing possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events that you subscribe to via DocuSign Connect and the events trigger email notifications to senders are managed entirely separately -- there is no correlation whatsoever between how you manage those two categories of events.

You can configure which Envelope events will trigger email notifications to a specific sender by updating the **Sending notification** settings for that particular **User** in your DocuSign account.  The **Sending notification** settings that you specify for a particular user will apply for *all* Envelopes that person sends (until if/when those settings are changed for the user) -- you can not configure email notification settings for a sender on a per-Envelope basis.

For information about how a User can configure their own email notification settings manually via the DocuSign web UI, see:  https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-manage-notifications.

[image]

If you want to use the API to automatically configure email notification settings for senders in your account, you can do so by using the **Update User Settings** operation, as described here in the docs: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Users/Users/updateSettings. Just keep in mind that, as mentioned previously, the settings you specify for a user will apply to *all* Envelopes that user sends (until if/when the settings are updated again).

Comment: Thank you so much, Kim. I didn't realize that the events being raised by Connect and the events generating emails were separate.

Answer (score 1):

Connect Trigger events which you can subscribe to are
[image]

As a Sender you can modify sender specific notifications. Please check [Envelope Notifications](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-manage-notifications) to know how to manage the notifications.

Comment: But what I want to know is can we listen for all the events like sent, created, signed, declined, etc, but only notify the sender that the envelope was declined.

Comment: I have edited my answer with the events which you can subscriber to in DocuSign using DocuSign Connect.